# Accessing MS Graph resources with Intune SDK

Tags: ios, microsoft-graph-api, intune

We are using the iOS Intune SDK to build a native MAM app. This app needs to access the Graph API to read the user profile and other data. What we did:

(1) We registered a app and gave the permissions: User.Read (for Graph and Windows Azure AD), DeviceManagementManagedApp.ReadWrite

Login and enrollment to Intune is working, the app gets enrolled. But, when trying to obtain the access token for the Graph API using the ADAL SDK I need to sign in again a then I am blocked with the message that the device needs to be managed to access this resource.

Do I need another permission? Where to I get the access token from? Is anything else missing?

Answer (score 1):

---

From your description it appears you have a Conditional Access policy enabled that requires mobile devices are Intune MDM managed.  When you call the Graph API from an unmanaged device it will ask you to enroll the device.  If you remove the Conditional Access policy you should be able to confirm this.